# Is it possible to build a progressive web app with react-strap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, progressive-web-apps

I want to build an progressive web app and currently I'm am using react strap but I don't have any idea if it is possible to build an progressive web app with this.

Comment: create-react-app is a PWA by default. Up to you to manage data synchronization though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can build progressive applications using react-strap.
This library give you access to bootstrap react component, to make your application progressive you just need to keep using the React framework.